# Can only run tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I migrated from Eclipse Adt to Android Studio, and under run the only option i have is to run "All Tests". How can I run the App as normal android app in the simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch the run configuration with the drop down as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

Afterwards, click on the run or debug button to the right of the drop down in the toolbar.

If you need to add a new run configuration you have multiple options:

You can go to `Edit Configurations...` (from there or the Run menu) and configure a new run configuration. To add a new configuration manually you need to find the big `+` button on the top left. (Most of the time I use "Android Application", "Android Test" or plain "JUnit"). On the right hand side you can select USB device or emulator.

A quicker way to run an activity (assuming it's launchable) or all tests from a single file or package is to just right-click on the class or package, and click on "Run 'name' ". This can be done from the project pane. For single class files this can be done from the code editor, too. To run a single test you can right-click inside the test method and do the same.